# How to cancel browser close/refresh confirm modal when refreshing page manually?

Tags: javascript

I have the browser show confirm modal when the user clicks the browser's refresh or close buttons with the code below:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmCloseOrRefresh;
function confirmCloseOrRefresh() {
   var confirmMessage = confirm('Are you sure to exit?');
   return confirmMessage;
}
```

Now, I have a custom refresh button on my page which I want to manually refresh the page without showing the confirm modal.

I tried this:

```
onRefreshButtonClick(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   window.location.reload();
   return true;
}
```

Still shows the confirm modal. Any way to cancel/override the confirm modal in this function?

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = null;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply introduce a global Boolean variable `restrictUnload` which you check in your `confirmCloseOrRefresh` function:

```
var restrictUnload = true;

function confirmCloseOrRefresh() {
   if (restrictUnload) {
     var confirmMessage = confirm('Are you sure to exit?');
     return confirmMessage;
   } else {
     return true;
   }
}
```

In your `onRefreshButtonClick` function, simply set that variable to `false`:

```
onRefreshButtonClick(event) {
   restrictUnload = false;
   event.preventDefault();
   window.location.reload();
   return true;
}
```